# Variance of sample mean of correlated RVs

Tags: probability, variance

Given the RVs $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$, with each $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j) = 1$.

I want to compute the variance of the sample mean $\overline{X}$ using the general definition of the variance of the sum of RVs:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\overline{X}) &= \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i\right) 
\\&= \frac1N \left( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \operatorname{Var}(X_i) +  \sum_{i\neq j} \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\right) 
\\&= \frac1N \left(N + \sum_{i\neq j} \operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\right)
\end{align}

Is my approach correct? What is the value of the sum of the covariances?

Answer (score 2):

The factor outside is $\frac 1 { N^{2}}$ and not $\frac  1 N$. The last sum is nothing but $N(N-1)$, the number of choices for $(i,j)$ with $ i \neq j$.

Comment: Did you mean that the sum evaluates to N(N-1) ?

Comment: The answer is $\frac 1 {N^{2}} (N+(N^{2}-N))=1$. @Morcus